# Google Maps API V3 grey box on one site, works fine on another

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a site 
http://beta.aico.co.uk/trained-installers.html, when this loads I get a grey box. I have the same code on the following site (different template) http://joomla.bemoore.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22&Itemid=29 and this works fine.  Therefore I suppose it must be a CSS issue, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it might be.

Has anyone got an idea where the problem is?

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: the first site is not accessible :)

Comment: Hi Sorry about that, it should be available in a few minutes !

Comment: I found an error in the first site `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromLatLngToDivPixel' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a CSS issue.  Here is the CSS rule that is the culprit:

```
div {
overflow: hidden !important;
overflow-y: hidden !important;
overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

Line 397 of trained-installers.html

You'll need to modify the rule to only apply to relevant DIVs, not all DIVs.